# Comparing ELBO of a VAE for different samples

Tags: likelihood, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

I am lacking of an interpretation of the evidence lower bound (ELBO), when comparing two different samples $x_1, x_2 \sim X$.
Writing the marginal log-likelihood as the sum of lower variational bound and the KL-Divergence between the approximated ($q$) and true ($p$) posterior as

$L=L^V + D_{KL}(q(z|x)||p(z|x))$.

A variational autoencoder (VAE) is able to estimate a value for $L^V$ for any $x$.
Now let's say we calculate values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ with the outcome of

$L^V(x_1)<L^V(x_2)$

Can the two likelihoods $L(x_1)$ and $L(x_2)$ can be compared as well, like

$L^V(x_1)<L^V(x_2) \Rightarrow L(x_1) < L(x_2)$  **?**

The reason why I am worrying is the KL-Divergence and the approximator $q(z|x)$ of the posterior. 
The hyperparameters of $q$ are not constant in a VAE, they a rather calculated given $x$ and thus, $D_{KL}$ is not constant as well.

Comment: you train the VAE for a given dataset to maximize the ELBO and to minimize the KLD. the "comparing ELBO values" holds then for the samples from this training dataset. If you assume the statistics of the training dataset and the test dataset are similar, then the comparison of the ELBO values should hold for test samples as well. If your test samples are entirely different than your training samples, then the model will definitely fail, but you usually assume this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But a trained encoder of the VAE produces different hyperparameters for the posterior $q(z|x)$ for different $x$. Thus, the KLD should be different. Or is the encoder of the VAE literally the posterior function?

Comment: for every x in your training set the hyperparsmeters of q(z|x) are different, right? it is the same principle. if your test sample x is close to your training samples, then the hyper parameters for the test sample will be similar to the hyperparsmeters of the training sample...